# Simply returning success or failure from ajax call in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

I have a little ajax call that calls rails:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '...',
        data: ({    ...
                }),
        success:    function(response, status) {
                    console.log(status);
        }
     });
```

In the rails controller I'm simply deleting an entry from the database, and I simply want to return if it was successful or not. What's the best way?

Should I just return JSON in respond_to? If so, what exactly would you have it contain?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Best way to signify success in this way is to put the following in your controller...

```
def destroy
  # ... your code ...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { head :ok }
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks! for the record, for a failure it might be something like:         format.json  { render :json => @obj.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }

Comment: I read that just returning ok may not work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791499/jquery-doesnt-call-success-method-on-ajax-for-rails-standard-rest-delete-answ

Comment: I was using `format.json { head :no_content }` as I don't want to send any data. But browser was trying to redirect to an url after ajax success, which is unexpected. I replaced it with `format.json { head :ok }` and unnecessary redirection gone.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I ended up having to render nil with a status code: `render json: nil, status: :ok`

Answer (score 12):

try this it's working for me

```ruby
def destroy 
  render json: {}, status: 200
end
```

Answer (score 4):

I found this shorter way to do the job:

```
def destroy
  # ... your code ...
  head :ok # this will return HTTP 200 OK to jQuery!
end
```

Comment: This returns a 200 to jQuery along with a single space in the reponse.   jQuery does not interpret this as a success.  So it will return success but not call the success callback.

Comment: Wow, this was actually patched.  I stand corrected!

Answer (score 0):

When you execute your query it might be returning some code that says it executed succesfully to confirm that row was deleted. So you can return that just to make sure query was also executed successfully along with the ajax call.

Comment: Right, I know if my query was successful or not, but HOW do you suggest returning that? For example: format.json { "false" } or render :nothing => true, or ..?