# jQuery ajax:error runs even if the response is OK 200

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have a form which submit a form via AJAX with :remote => true. Looking at the server log and FireBug, I get the response 200 OK and it returns JSON in the form of:

```
{ "email": "test@test.com"}
```

then I have these two handlers:

```
$('#new_invitation').bind("ajax:success", function(event, data, status, xhr) {
    alert('test');
});

$('#new_invitation').bind("ajax:error", function() {
    alert('error');
});
```

and even if I get back a 200OK, it is the error handler that fires. The only time I managed to make the success handler work was when I send a empty response with 200 in the header.

I can't figure out why this isnt working :-S

EDIT 1------------
After doing these changes:

```
$('#new_invitation').bind("ajaxSuccess", function(event, data, status, xhr) {
    alert('test');
});

$('#new_invitation').bind("ajaxError", function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
alert('error');
    console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
    console.log(textStatus.responseText);
    console.log(errorThrown.responseText);
});
```

I am still getting the same error. The log stuff gives me:

```
undefined
my_email@test.com
undefined
```

Here is the code for the form (standard Rails stuff):

```
<%= form_for @shoot.invitations.new, :url=>shoot_invitations_path(@shoot), :remote => true, :html => {:class => 'form-inline'} do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :email, :'placeholder' => 'ex: test@test.com' %>
    <%= f.text_field :role, :'placeholder' => 'ex: Photographer' %>
    <%= f.submit "Invite", :class => 'btn btn-success' %>
<% end %>
```

EDIT 2 ---------

I did a few changes and now it seems my error is a parse error. I dont understand because this is the JSON I am getting back from the server (data.responseText), which seems all good:

```
{"email":"zxxczxc@test.com"}
```

ANSWER ---------
I managed to have everything work when I put :'data-type' => :json in the form options. I tried this before and it did not work because I put it in the form_tag options and not the html options...

Comment: console.log all three arguments, more than likely you are getting parseerror which would mean invalid json.

Comment: Kevin=> I am not even responding with JSON. I did at first but not I am just rendering a text string and it still fails.

Comment: @Alain, what does the ajax call look like? Please show that code.

Comment: @JonathanM I did not have to write any code, it is the default jQuery UJS stuff that is automatically added when you use :remote => true in the form... Unless you are talking about something else?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If the server returns something that isn't valid JSON, such as a single space, jQuery will generate a parse error and consider it a failed request even if the status code is 200.

As of jQuery 1.9 a completely empty response is considered a failed request when the type is set to JSON since an empty string is invalid JSON. See http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-ajax-returning-a-json-result-of-an-empty-string.

Answer (score 8):

1. Check that $.ajax's datatype is set to jsonp
2. Try to return {email:"ahsgah@ahsgh.com"}

Comment: without the quotes around the email

Comment: I found my issue (edited question) and I am giving you +1 because you are the one that brought me to it.

Answer (score 2):

JSON.parse('') throws an error.  To me, that is stupid, it should return undefined.
I added this code to my app

```
#HACK JSON.parse('') should return undefined, not throw an error
_parse = JSON.parse
JSON.parse = (str) =>
  unless str == ''
    _parse.apply JSON, arguments
```

or for u poor people not using coffeescript ( untested )

```
//HACK JSON.parse('') should return undefined, not throw an error
var _parse = JSON.parse
JSON.parse = function(str) {
  if (str !== '')
    return _parse.apply(JSON, arguments);
  else
    return undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ajaxSuccess` instead of `ajax:success`, and `ajaxError` instead of `ajax:error` for your eventTypes.

See here: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events

Comment: urm.. I'm not sure about this one. It says ajaxError is a global event - I think the intent is to use it to globally log errors, or perhaps to show and hide a processing icon. Generally you want the error callback to be local and attached to the original ajax call. Plus since this question was asked the error callback is deprecated anyway in preference for Deferred.fail (http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/)

Comment: @Simon_Weaver, the OP indicates it was part of the answer. At the time, it wasn't deprecated.

Comment: that's why I said 'Plus since this question was asked...' :-)
I'm not sure what you meant by it being part of the answer though

Comment: @Simon_Weaver, yeah, he incorporated it in the first edit, and it continued through to the finished version.

Answer (score 0):

(On Rails 5.2 and jQuery 2) I spent an hour comparing two bits of UJS code side-by-side to no avail: both return a similar format Javascript function call (to update the front-end), and a status of 200 but one triggers `ajax:error` and the other doesn't. I was able to eliminate the problem by switching from **jquery_ujs** to **rails-ujs** in the **application.js** manifest:

```
//= require jquery2
// require jquery_ujs  # Removed this by taking away '='
//= require rails-ujs
```

Note the hyphen vs the underline!

Now both calls behave the same (correct) way. I hope this helps someone else.