# Backbone Create

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

For some reason this.collection.create() is returning an error, but interestingly, the error message seems like the model I just added to my collection.

```
this.collection.create({
    name: $('#big-input').val(),
    firstRemark: $('#small-input').val(),
    postedBy: window.user.displayName,
    twitterHandle: window.user.twittername,
    pictureUrl: window.user.profilePic

},{wait: true,    

  success: function(response){
     console.log("success");
     console.log(response)

  },
  error:function(err){
      console.log(err)

   }

});
```

this is what I get after console.log(err):

[image]

```
exports.newPost = function(req, res){
  console.log("GOT NEW TWEET REQUEST");
  var newPost = new Post(req.body)
  newPost.dateCreated = new Date();
  newPost.save();
  res.send(200);
};
```

Thanks to answers below I was able to print my 'real' error. As seen below `xhr.responseText` is 'OK' and 'status' is 200. Why is this response triggering a success but an error?

[image]

I also have a parse method in my collection

```
parse: function(response){
    this.page = response.page;
    this.perPage = response.perPage;
    this.total = response.total;
    this.noofpages =response.noofpages;

    return response.posts;
},
```

Comment: How does the request and response look like

Comment: Do you have a `validate` or `parse` method on your model?

Comment: @kalley I have a parse method on my collection, edited my answer

Comment: Your server need to return a respond body with `200` request. see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14225337/832759

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected.  Have a look at [the Model.Save documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save), which says the error callback will be called with `(model, xhr, options)` as it's parameters.

If you want the actual contents of the response you can get it from the second parameters `responseText` property: `xhr.responseText`.  There's more details on jqXHR elements in the jquery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

The parameters of your success callback are also not quite right - it takes `(model, response, options)`

EDIT:

Not entirely sure if it's the cause of your problems, but your server should be returning a 200 status code and the models JSON on success.  Have a look at the [Backbone.Sync](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) documentation.

From looking at the code this does look important when passing `wait: true` as an option, as the attributes set are extended with the returned attributes from the server.  Have a look at the options.success function used by backbone [here](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-62) to see what I mean.  It certainly looks like something might go wrong if you return "OK" from the server, though I'm not sure if it'd be exactly the problem you're experiencing.

EDIT2: Slight correction to what I wrote above: The return value gets passed through `Model.parse`.  Since you've defined a custom parse function, the server should return something that is going to work with it, rather than just plain JSON for the model.

Comment: console.log(xhr.responseText) just prints 'OK'.. this makes me wonder why the success callback is not triggered?

Comment: @GorkemYurtseven I've added a possible explanation.  Not sure if I'm correct though.

Answer (score 3):

The error function will receive 3 arguments as defined in the `wrapError` function in backbone.js

```
  model.trigger('error', model, resp, options);
```

Therefore what your output is, is correct. You will want to add a variable to your error function to capture the response (2nd argument) and log that instead to help you debug.