# Rails: "head :ok" interpreted as "ajax:error"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery doesn’t call success method on $.ajax for rails standard REST DELETE answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791499/jquery-doesnt-call-success-method-on-ajax-for-rails-standard-rest-delete-answ)

I respond to a remote-link *(data-remote="true" data-type="json")* and output

```
format.json { head :ok }
```

in my Rails (3.2.6) controller, which creates this header:

```
Status Code:200 OK
```

---

```
...
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Server:thin 1.4.1 codename Chromeo
Set-Cookie: ... path=/; HttpOnly
X-UA-Compatible:IE=Edge
...
```

In my JavaScript file **ajax:complete** is triggered and outputs **200** *(data.status)*.

```
  $( '#myElement' ).on( 'ajax:complete', function( e, data ) {
    console.log( data.status );
  });
```

*data* looks like this:

```
 ...
 readyState: 4
 responseText: " "
 setRequestHeader: function ( name, value ) {...
 state: function () {...
 status: 200
 statusCode: function ( map ) {...
 statusText: "OK"
 ...
```

*Looks pretty good to me...*

### The problem

Instead of **ajax:success**, jQuery *(jquery-ujs)* executes **ajax:error** and I have no idea why since no error is given.

I have looked into alot of discussions, but this way always seemed to be the solution, not the problem. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791499/jquery-doesnt-call-success-method-on-ajax-for-rails-standard-rest-delete-answ).

jQuery is expecting a JSON response. "head :ok" has a single space for the response body, so jQuery fails to parse the JSON response so it still considers the 200 status code an error.

You can have Rails respond with `head :no_content` which has an empty body or a `render :json=>true`

This was discussed in Rails [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1742).

The reason for the single space in `head :ok` in Rails is a workaround in an old Safari bug.

Comment: The trouble with using `head :no_content` as that it doesn't seem to touch my ajax success handler

Comment: What if you are expecting :js back, "head :ok" works with a :js repsonse?