# Why does Rails want to return "head :no_content" for JSON PUT requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After I run
`rails generate scaffold User`
The generated controller function in Rails 3.2.11 for updating a user looks like this:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

The line I'm curious about is returning `head :no_content` for a successful JSON update request.  I've done some googling, as I was guessing that this is some sort of RESTful property, to not return the updated object, but I couldn't find anything that claimed that was the case.

Why is this the default, versus returning the JSON representation of the User object post-update?

Comment: Great question, I was wondering the exact same thing.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Good question, apparently the purpose is to return a HTTP status code 200 with an empty body, see [this discussion](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1742). Maybe for brevity or security purposes. `head :no_content` seems to create a HTTP response 200 (success) with an empty body, returning this response header:

```
Status Code:200 OK
```

see also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407328/rails-head-ok-interpreted-as-ajaxerror).

Comment: I am actually seeing `head :no_content` return a 204 No Content, which doesn't seem to fire the `ajax:success` event.

Comment: If you want to explicitly return 200, use `head 200`. Even `head :ok` will return 304 not modified on subsequent requests.

Comment: @DamienRoche on a `GET` request, you will want a `304 Not Modified` to be returned if the resources has truly not been modified, as this is needed for HTTP caching to work. To ensure best results set expires/last-modified headers and/or etag headers too.

Comment: that `:ok` should be changed, it's confusing that it returns 304 on subsequent requests... which conditions make it 304?

Comment: `head :ok` seems to return 200 always for me.